# Visitors Contacting Authors

Tags: contact

Is there any way that I can have a website user be able to contact a post author.
The website user must not be required to be logged in to the website.
I guess a form to email the post author might be the way to go, but it must be simple to use, and avoid spam.
Is there such a plugin for wordpress that can handle this?

Comment: Contact Form 7 or Gravity Forms is the way to go, a couple of simple hooks pulled at the correct time and it will be routed to the `$post->post_author`'s email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive done this before using both contact form 7 and Grunion Contact Form plugins, when using contact form 7 i created a new tag to send the email to the post author:

```
//contact form 7 author email
wpcf7_add_shortcode('author_email', 'wpcf7_expert_email_shortcode_handler', true);

function wpcf7_expert_email_shortcode_handler($tag) {
    if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

    $name = $tag['name'];
    if (empty($name)) return '';
    global $post;
    //get author email:
    $author_mail = get_the_author_meta('user_email',$post->post_author);
    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $author_mail . '" />';
    return $html;
}

/*
* Usage: in contact form 7 form area add
* [author_email unique_name]
* and in to email address add
* [unique_name]
*/
```

and with Grunion i called it directly from the template using:

```
global $post;
$author_mail = get_the_author_meta('user_email',$post->post_author);
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form subject="message from.'$post->post_title.'" to="'.$author_mail.'"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) can do this without any coding. When you create the contact form, use the [special mail tag](http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/) `[_post_author_email]` as the "To" value in the *Mail* tab. Then place the contact form shortcode in a post, and emails should go to the post author's email address. I just tested it with Contact Form 7 v4.3.1 and it seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [Grunion Contact Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/grunion-contact-form/) for this. Works like a charm. Ties into Akismet for spam filtering. It's very simple to use--you can insert a shortcode into your post content, or insert a "[do shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)" function into your template. Works either way.

Comment: Thanks Adam!
I've accepted Bainternet's answer purely as it also included the required code to achieve the objective. Many thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress Comments without displaying them on the site.  The Author will be notified, the comments can be managed well and there are built-in functions and plugins to help with spam.